# Obfuscating js files with grunt-obfuscator: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

I was searching over the internet about how to obfuscate my JavaScript code and after use uglify that convert all my files minified but not obfuscated I decided to use [grunt-obfuscator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-obfuscator)

After make this configuration on my simple project:

**Gruntfile.js**

```
  module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-obfuscator');

  grunt.initConfig({
    connect: {
      server: {
        options: {
          port: 9000,
          base: 'app/'
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      project: {
        files: ['app/**/*.js', 'app/**/*.html', 'app/**/*.json', 'app/**/*.css'],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      }
    },
    obfuscator: {
      files: [
        'app/js/app.js',
        'app/js/controllers.js'
      ],
      entry: 'app/js/app.js',
      out: 'app/js/obfuscated.js',
      strings: true,
      root: __dirname
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['obfuscator', 'connect', 'watch']);

};
```

**My app.js**

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module('myapp', [
            'ngRoute',
            'myapp.controllers'
        ]);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }]);
    
})();
```

**My controller.js**

```
(function() {
    angular.module('myapp.controllers', [])
        .controller('AppController', ['$scope',
         function ($scope) {
            $scope.name = "Test123";
        }]);
})();
```

After execute **grunt** my `obfuscated.js` is really hard to read, which is really great. So I'm enter to my localhost which is loading now the `obfuscated.js` file but I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

1. What am I missing?

**My obfuscated.js**

```
!function(a,b){function c(b,d){var e,f;if("\x2e"!=b[0]&&"\x2f"!=b[0])return a(b);if(d=d||"\x72\x6f\x6f\x74",e=c.resolve(b),!e&&/\.json$/i.test(b))return a("\x2e\x2f"+c.basename(b));if(f=c.cache[e],!f)try{return a(b)}catch(g){throw Error("\x66\x61\x69\x6c\x65\x64\x20\x74\x6f\x20\x72\x65\x71\x75\x69\x72\x65\x20\x22"+b+"\x22\x20\x66\x72\x6f\x6d\x20"+d+"\n"+g.message+"\n"+g.stack)}return f.exports||(f.exports={},f.call(f.exports,f,f.exports,c.relative(e))),f.exports}c.cache={},c.basename=a("\x70\x61\x74\x68").basename,c.resolve=function(b){var d,e,f;if("\x2e"!=b[0])return a.resolve(b);for(d=[b,b+"\x2e\x6a\x73",b+"\x2f\x69\x6e\x64\x65\x78\x2e\x6a\x73",b+"\x2e\x6a\x73\x6f\x6e",b+"\x2f\x69\x6e\x64\x65\x78\x2e\x6a\x73\x6f\x6e"],e=0;f=d[e];e++)if(c.cache[f])return f},c.register=function(a,b){c.cache[a]=b},c.relative=function(a){function b(b){var d,e,f,g,h;if("\x2e"!=b[0])return c(b);for(d=a.split("\x2f"),e=b.split("\x2f"),d.pop(),f=0,g=e.length;g>f;f+=1)h=e[f],"\x2e\x2e"==h?d.pop():"\x2e"!=h&&d.push(h);return c(d.join("\x2f"),a)}return b.resolve=c.resolve,b.cache=c.cache,b},c.register("\x2e\x2f\x61\x70\x70\x2f\x6a\x73\x2f\x61\x70\x70\x2e\x6a\x73",function(a,b,c){!function(){var a=angular.module("\x6d\x79\x61\x70\x70",["\x6e\x67\x52\x6f\x75\x74\x65","\x6d\x79\x61\x70\x70\x2e\x63\x6f\x6e\x74\x72\x6f\x6c\x6c\x65\x72\x73"]);a.config(["\x24\x72\x6f\x75\x74\x65\x50\x72\x6f\x76\x69\x64\x65\x72",function(a){a.when("\x2f",{templateUrl:"\x76\x69\x65\x77\x73\x2f\x68\x6f\x6d\x65\x2e\x68\x74\x6d\x6c"}).otherwise({redirectTo:"\x2f"})}]),c.extensions["\x2e\x73\x65\x72\x76\x65\x72\x2e\x63\x6f\x6e\x74\x72\x6f\x6c\x6c\x65\x72\x2e\x6a\x73"]=c.extensions["\x2e\x6a\x73"],c.extensions["\x2e\x73\x65\x72\x76\x65\x72\x2e\x6d\x6f\x64\x65\x6c\x2e\x6a\x73"]=c.extensions["\x2e\x6a\x73"],c.extensions["\x2e\x73\x65\x72\x76\x65\x72\x2e\x72\x6f\x75\x74\x65\x73\x2e\x6a\x73"]=c.extensions["\x2e\x6a\x73"]}()}),c.register("\x2e\x2f\x61\x70\x70\x2f\x6a\x73\x2f\x63\x6f\x6e\x74\x72\x6f\x6c\x6c\x65\x72\x73\x2e\x6a\x73",function(){!function(){angular.module("\x6d\x79\x61\x70\x70\x2e\x63\x6f\x6e\x74\x72\x6f\x6c\x6c\x65\x72\x73",[]).controller("\x41\x70\x70\x43\x6f\x6e\x74\x72\x6f\x6c\x6c\x65\x72",["\x24\x73\x63\x6f\x70\x65",function(a){a.name="\x54\x65\x73\x74\x31\x32\x33"}])}()}),b.exports=c("\x2e\x2f\x61\x70\x70\x2f\x6a\x73\x2f\x61\x70\x70\x2e\x6a\x73")}(require,module);
```

**UPDATE**
There is no answer for this question since this plugin is not created for angularjs, only for Node.js. And the creator has not the minimal intention to make it for angular js. However it is a cool tool

Answer (score 2):

there are several questions here.

**Do I need to obfuscate all my js files in order to get this run?**
no

**An obfuscate file can work perfect with all your dependencies NON-obfuscated?** yes

**What am I missing?**
Hard to tell, uglification can be very tricky.
First I'll verify if dependencies injections are well done or you can use [ngAnnotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) to do that for you
dependency shall be defined as example bellow:

```
.service('myService',['$rootScope',function($rootScope){ ... }]);
```

If that does not solve your issue, you have to dig on requireJS that seems to send an issue

Edit your code and paste your main.js for us see what you are trying to uglify

Comment: Thanks for the first two answers. My app works fine if all the libraries are minified, I have the problem just in the obfuscate process. Please see my edit question.